# Range of Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I'm trying to compute the density for the range $R_n$ for samples of a random variable $X$ that are uniformly distributed on the interval $(a,b)$.  We define the range as

$$
R_n = X_{(n)} - X_{(1)},
$$

where $X_{(i)}$ is the $i$-th smallest sample of $X$.  The theoretical density (which I got from Allan Gut's *Intermediate Probability*) is

$$
f_{R_n}(r) = n (n - 1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty (F_X(x + r) - F_X(x))^{n-2} f_X(x + r)f_X(u) \;\text{d}u
$$

and substituting $F$'s and $f$'s yields

$$
= n (n - 1) \int_a^{b - r} \left(\frac{r - 2a}{b - a}\right)^{n-2}\left(\frac{1}{b - a}\right)^2 \;\text{d}u
$$

which finally simplifies to

$$
 = n (n - 1) \left(\frac{r - 2a}{b - a}\right)^{n - 2}\left(\frac{1}{b - a}\right)^2 (b - a - r) 
$$

Now, this seems reasonable, but I sort of guessed at the limits of integration.  Does this look right?

---

**Edit in response to closing as duplicate:**

As far as I can tell, this question is different from the one posted because it is more general.  I am quantifying over uniform distributions on arbitrary intervals.  It is also more specific, since I am confused about the domain on which I am integrating.

Comment: Since the range of a sample from the uniform distribution on the interval (a,b) is obviously (b-a) times the range of a sample from the uniform distribution on the interval (0,1), this looks very much like [a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33767) to me.

Comment: Your first mistake is to write $f_X(u)du$ instead of $f_X(x)dx$. The second is the numerator $r-2a$ in the fraction, which should read $r-2x$ (or $r-2u$ if you switch to the dummy variable $u$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Density and expectation of the range of a sample of uniform random variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33767/density-and-expectation-of-the-range-of-a-sample-of-uniform-random-variables)

Comment: Another duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/421730/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is OK. The density of the Uniform$(a,b)$ is given by
$$f_X(u) = \frac{1}{b-a} 1_{(a,b)}(u)$$
so the expression
$$f_X(u+r)f_X(u) = \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} 1_{(a,b)}(u+r) 1_{(a,b)}(u)$$
is equivalent to
$$ \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} 1_{(a-r,b-r)}(u) 1_{(a,b)}(u) = \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} 1_{(a,b-r)}(u)$$
provided $r < b-a$.